# Implications of Hadoop Erasure Coding and WORM Pricinple

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I just read about the [Erasure Coding](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0-alpha1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSErasureCoding.html) HDFS feature in the upcoming Hadoop 3.0. If I understand it correctly, the data within a block gets divided into smaller units (striping cells) and then analyzed for similarity. I imagine this kind of similar to dimensionality reduction: The simularities will be stored in so called parity cells and since simular patterns don't need to be saved multiple times but can be referenced this is more storage efficient.

But probably erasure coding only works efficient if there are many stripping cells which can be compared so that similarities can be referenced as often as possible. However adding new data / stripping cells will result in the need to change all parity cells. Since updates are not part of HDFS (WORM = write once, read many), pobably all parity cells would need to be rewritten.

So will erasure coding lead to a massive I/O need or am I mixing something up?